# How do I run a rails service with rake db:seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a service set up in app/services that pulls articles from a Govt. API for travel warnings and advisories (see below). What I'd like to do is run this code which parses the response and saves to my database when I run rake db:seed. I'm not sure how to run this from the seed file - could i just run Govt.request_data ?

```
class Govt    

def self.request_data
  travel_alerts = request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TAs.xml')
  travel_warnings = request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TWs.xml')

  warnings_array = travel_warnings["rss"]["channel"]["item"]
  alerts_array = travel_alerts["rss"]["channel"]["item"]

  parse_and_save(warnings_array)
  parse_and_save(alerts_array)
end

def self.parse_and_save(advisory_array)
  advisory_array.each do |element|
    country_name_regex = element["title"].match(/.+?(?= Travel)/)
    country = Country.find_by(name: country_name_regex.to_s)

    if country 
      country.update(
        title: element["title"], 
        description: element["description"],
        publication_date: element["pubDate"])
      if element["description"].include?("This Travel Warning")
        country.update(advisory_type: "warning")
      else
        country.update(advisory_type: "alert")
      end
    end
  end
end

def self.request_data(link)
  Hash.from_xml(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(link)).body)
end

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-architectured your code to make things simpler.

```
class Govt

  def self.request_data(link)
    hash_from_api = Hash.from_xml(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(link)).body)
  end

  def self.get_array(hash_from_api)
    travel_alerts = request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TAs.xml')
    alerts_array = travel_alerts["rss"]["channel"]["item"]
  end

  def self.parse_and_save(advisory_array)
    advisory_array.each do |element|
      country_name_regex = element["title"].match(/.+?(?= Travel)/)
      country = Country.find_by(name: country_name_regex.to_s)

      if country
        country.update(
          title: element["title"],
          description: element["description"],
          publication_date: element["pubDate"])
        if element["description"].include?("This Travel Warning")
          country.update(advisory_type: "warning")
        else
          country.update(advisory_type: "alert")
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Inside your rake task you can do something like this

```
travel_alert_hash    = Govt.request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TAs.xml')
travel_warnings_hash = Govt.request_data('http://travel.state.gov/_res/rss/TAs.xml')

alerts_array   = Govt.get_array(travel_alert_hash)
warnings_array = Govt.get_array(travel_warnings_hash)

Govt.parse_and_save(alerts_array)
Govt.parse_and_save(warnings_array)
```

Of course you can refactor the above code, according to your needs, but that's the basic gist of it. Let me know if it fits your need.

EDIT: I've created a sample application to for testing, and everything seems to be working as expected. Let me know if you need access to sample application. I would be more than happy to share the codebase.

Comment: Thanks Rahul - this seems like that I'm looking for!